What does "position-wise" fully connected mean?
I understand the architecture of a position-wise feed-forward network as described in (https://nn.labml.ai/transformers/feed_forward.html). However I do not understand what "position wise" refers to. I assume "position" refers to where a data point is inside the input vector/matrix. What makes this architecture "position-wise"?

Position-Wise basically means that the architecture takes position of a given value in the vector into considiration, and changing position of a given value in the input will impact the output.
